# storing a url for a redirect rails as solution to 'redirect loop' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three controller actions which list different scoped workflow types of the same object. In the same controller I have another action which performs a state change on the object depending what's clicked in the view. I had placed a `redirect_to request.referer`in the method that toggles the sate but this cause a loop error if the link was clicked repeated.
so i tried this instead

```
  before_action :request_url, except: [:toggle_field]
  def rejected
    @workflow_body = 'Rejected'
    @entries = Photo.with_rejected_state.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def toggle_field
    raise
    if @entry.toggle_state!(params[:approve], @entry)
      flash[:notice] = "The entry was #{@entry.workflow_state}"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was a problem"
    end    
    redirect_to @location
  end

private

  def request_url
    @location = request.original_url
  end
```

This isn't working. The variable is nil by the time it reaches the toggle_field redirect. I think it could be my lack of understanding of how Ruby exposes variables within a class, I don't know.

Comment: Your `@location` variable assigned in the `request-url` method. This method gets invoked before every action in the controller **except** the `toggle_field` action, because you've set this in your `before_action` helper. Therefore, when the `toggle_field` come to the `redirect_to` it sees the nil object, because `@location` returns nothing, because the `request_url` method doesn't work with this method. 

You need `before_action :request_url` or `before_action :request_url, only: [:toggle_field]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request_url` is not called on `toggle_field` action: you explicitly exclude it using `except: [:toggle_field]`. Try removing `except: [:toggle_field]`.